# Do I have to create a contract for library?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm writing a contract which calls my written library. when I deploy it in remix-ide, I see that I have to submit twice on MetaMask. 
Does it mean I have to create a contract for my library?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You have to deploy the library. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6927/what-are-the-steps-to-compile-and-deploy-a-library-in-solidity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [Oficial Documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#libraries),  libraries must be deployed exactly as a contract with the difference that they are deployed only once at a specific address and then can be reused by different contracts.